# change the AWS CLI from 1 to 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, pip, aws-cli

When checking the AWS PATH with `which aws` when changing the AWS CLI from 1 to 2

```
/Users/username/.pyenv/shims/aws
```

I used to install via pyenv, but I want to remove it and install it according to system 2, but even if I try it according to the official doc, it is not changed to system 2.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-mac.html

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.pkg" -o "AWSCLIV2.pkg"
sudo installer -pkg AWSCLIV2.pkg -target /
```

It did not change to the 2 system even if I typed this command.

I've also tried uninstalling the AWS CLI, but it doesn't work.
Does anyone know of any way to do this?

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I removed my old aws cli from `~/.pyenv/versions/x.x.x/bin/aws`, where x.x.x is the current Python version.

Get the current version:

```
$ pyenv versions
* 3.7.4
```

Remove aws cli from current pyenv bin:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/bin/aws*
```

Try again `which aws`:

```
$ which aws 
/usr/local/bin/aws
```

Comment: thanks advice, But the path remains intact and that didn't solve the problem

Comment: @jadejoe Removing the shim manually worked for me. `rm ~/.pyenv/shims/aws`

Comment: I did not have to remove the shim, but with the `bin/aws*` files removed it goes back to the system installed AWS cli

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
This is because pyenv linked the shim to very Python version that command has been installed originally with; that's by the way ok to avoid version conflicts. pip3 and awscli v3 uninstall don't take care of that.
What you have to do is to:

1. First, uninstall the old awscli as noted in the AWS documentation (probably you used pip3). Note: remember to edit your bash_profile or zshrc as you may have a $HOME/.local/bin PATH in your config: you want to remove that too
2. The aws shim will remain in place until you get rid of that Python version (pyenv uninstall 3.7.x) BUT YOU PROBABLY DON'T WANT THAT
3. Just remove the shim manually `rm /Users/username/.pyenv/shims/aws`
4. Install the AWS CLI v2 using the recommended installed and verify everything works correctly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my Windows system because of I was having both AWS CLI and AWS CLI v2 installed but **PATH** environment variable was corrupted because of installing AWS CLI 2 multiple times.
I removed AWS CLI (means version 1) from that PATH or **Path** or path variable and I pointed to my AWS CLI v2 folder like **C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\aws.exe**. Then all my AWS CLI v2 and kubernate 0.xx.x all set by itself. When I check with aws --version, I get aws 2 version always now.

So, install AWS CLI 2 and also check your **path** system environment variable. I think no need of work around Python version. Please refer to AWS documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cliv2-migration-instructions.html#cliv2-migration-instructions-side-by-side